# Assuming a Solution Exists

Tags: proof-writing

Students who are beginning to learn proofs (and some seasoned pros) occasionally commit the error of assuming what they're trying to prove.  My question involves assuming at the onset that a solution to a problem exists, then using that existence to get the solution you assumed existed.  Two examples:

1. A common technique for proving that any function $f$ can be written as the sum of an even and an odd function is to assume such functions $O$ and $E$ exist, then note \begin{align*} f(x) &= E(x) + O(x) \\ f(-x) &= E(x) - O(x)\end{align*} and solve for $O(x)$ and $E(x)$.
2. A nested root such as $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\vphantom{2^5}3}}$ can be written as $\sqrt{1/2} + \sqrt{3/2}$ by first assuming there exist $A$ and $B$ such that $\sqrt A + \sqrt B$ is equal to the original radical, then solving for $A$ and $B$.

In general, when and how is it legal to assume the solution to a problem exists *a priori*?  Or do the ends justify the means?  Or is there some higher structure where the existence of solutions to the two problems above, and others like them, are proven, but I haven't gotten there yet (similar to telling Calc II students that a partial fraction decomposition exists, now find it)?

Comment: In both of those examples you show what the solution must be provided that it exists, and then you verify that this actually *is* a solution. In some other examples that I’ve seen the steps are interchangeable: you can show in either order that a solution must exist (e.g., that a certain sequence is convergent) and what it must be if it exists (e.g., what the limit is).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Proving a solution exists and then finding the solution I get.  The gray area is pointing at a problem and saying "*If* the solution exists then it would have this property, which leads to that, and ta-da!  Here's the solution I assumed existed."  I'm comfortable solving things in this manner, I'm just curious about justification.

Comment: But that isn't a grey area: it's simply incomplete. It only becomes a complete solution when you either prove that the *tentative* solution that you've obtained actually is a solution, or prove independently that there is a solution.

Comment: Your point being, assuming the solution exists will not alter whether or not a solution exists?  I guess I can buy that.

Comment: That's true, but it's not my point. My point is that you seem to be misunderstanding the arguments in question. In all of them one *does* prove that a solution exists, either independently of finding it, or by verifying that one's tentative solution actually *is* a solution.

Comment: I guess that's my main question.  For example, the fact that I even bother looking for an even and an odd function whose sum is $f$ means I have to have reason to believe those functions exist in the first place.  What tells me that?

Comment: In effect you’re asking how new results are discovered. That’s far too broad a question to be answered here, but experiment, observation, insight, and mathematical intuition all play a rôle.

Comment: No, I'm asking how *this* method of discovery, through assuming a solution exists beforehand, is valid.

Comment: Validity isn’t a concept that applies to methods of discovery. Suppose that you guess that some problem has a solution, assume that to be the case, and prove that the only possible solution is so-and-so. At this point you have not solved the problem; you’ve shown that **if** the problem has a solution, that solution must be so-and-so. You still don’t know whether the problem has a solution. Your result doesn’t become a solution of the problem until you either verify in some way that the only possible solution actually **is** a solution or show independently that there is a solution. And at ...

Comment: ... this point there is nothing remotely circular in the argument. It doesn’t matter whether you guessed the solution by discovering that the solution had to be so-and-so if it existed at all, or whether the Oracle of Delphi suggested it to you; in either case you still have to prove that it **is** a solution.

Comment: I call it "proof by admission" and use it to show that the function which gives the area under the curve of a function f is its primitive function, what is called the "indefinite integral" (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586107/what-is-the-difference-between-an-indefinite-integral-and-an-antiderivative).