# What is the function giving the area between $0$ and $x$ under $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: integration

Everyone says that it's $\ln|x|$, but that obviously can't be true because when $x=1, y$ is $0$, when it should be over $1$. I am nonplussed. By "integral" I mean the thing the function of the area under the curve. I don't know what other definition of "integral" this answer is using (I haven't taken calculus yet), but it isn't what I'm looking for.

As per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIx2N-viNwY at $1:05$ what I need is a "normalized sum", and I have no idea what that is and Google isn't any help.

Another way to phrase this question, if it is hindered by a misunderstanding of mine, is "What is the function of that graph at $1:05$?"

Comment: 'By the integral I mean the thing that sums values' well many 'things' sum values. And when you don't know the definition too should look for one before asking.

Comment: @Shamim The function that sums values.

Comment: Not entirely sure what youre saying.  The integral of 1/x is indeed ln|x|.  At x=0, the value of 1/x is not defined.  The slope near x=0 on the positive side is downward (or negative), which is implied by the ln|x| at the same near zero value.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum How do you explain that "when x=1 y is 0 when it should be over 1"? 1/x is positive from 0 to 1 so its integral should be too.

Comment: You seem to be confusing definite and indefinite integrals. Among other things possibly.

Answer (score 4):

You error comes from the fact that, for $x>0$, one of the definitions of the log is
$$\ln x=\int_{\color{red}1}^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t,\quad\text{so that }\enspace \ln1=\int_{1}^1\frac{\mathrm dt}t=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

People have pointed out that in your calculation you divide by $0$, and that using integration techniques doesn't make sense around $0$.

I still want to convince you that $\int x^{-1} dx = \ln(x)$ without using integration techniques, just using the definition of ln(x) and a little knowledge of derivatives. The following is a reproduction of an argument from **Calculus 3rd edition by Micheal Spivak**, which has stuck with me for years.

The main motivation behind a logarithm function, say $f$, is to compute multiplication/powers quickly.

We can compute powers quickly for numbers of the same base: $10^5 10^6$ can be done by adding the exponents $10^{5+6}$. We can formalize this property by assigning $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$. Taking $f(1) = 10$, satisfies multiplying powers of 10. Taking $f(1) = e$ satisfies this property for powers of e, etc... We want to find an inverse function to this function $f$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$. We, today, call this the log function.

I'm not sure if you've seen limits/derivatives yet, but by the limit definition and the  the property $f(x+y)= f(x)f(y)$:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)f(h) -f(x)}{h}$$

$$ = f(x) \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) -1}{f(h)} $$.

So since $f(0) = 1$ because any $a^0 = 1$, we get that:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) -1}{f(h)}$$

Now we assign $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{f(h)} = \alpha$, to simplify the expression to get:

$$f'(x) = f(x)\alpha $$.

So using the fact that the $\log_{a}$ function is supposed to be the inverse of $a^x$:

$$\log'_a(x) = (f^{-1}(x))' = \frac{1}{f'(f(x))}$$

With the above definitions:

$$= \frac{1}{\alpha f(f^{-1}(x))} =  \frac{1}{\alpha x} $$

(As in turns out, doing some other computations this constant $\alpha = 1$ when we take $f(x) = e^{x}$)

The integral, being the anti-derivate, means that $\log'_a x = \frac{1}{\alpha x}$ implies that $$\int{\frac{1}{\alpha x} dx} = \log_a x$$

This is an argument/proof that really took me by surprise when I was taking analysis! I hope anyone reading this thinks so too!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't evaluate $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x}dx $ over any interval containing $x = 0$. The definition will blow up in your face, and so any facts you learn about integrals **do not** apply if you try to "integrate over $0$".

Secondly, let's try an example where $x$ is on the negative side of the Reals. The function $1/x$ is negative there, so if we integrate from, say, $-4$ to $-2$, (which is the positive, or increasing $x$ direction), our integral should come out to be a negative number.

$$\int_{-4}^{-2} \frac{1}{x}dx  = \ln(|x|) \Biggr\rvert_{-4}^{-2} = \ln(|- 2|) - \ln(|-4|) = \ln\left(\frac{|2|}{|4|}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\ln(2)\lt 0$$

which does have the correct sign.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, hold on. The definition of an "integral" (specifically definite integral) is very geometric.  In simple single variable calculus, it is intuitively explained with area.  It is the AREA under a function between two points on the x-axis. Thats it. Pretty simple concept.

You can do an integral calculation in a number of different ways.  You can use simple geometric shapes.  You can use infinite sums (in a variety of different ways [see Riemann sums, Simpsons rule, trapezoid rule, and others, including Lebesgue, Gaussian quadrature]).

Sometimes this can be done with exactness, sometimes not. Sometimes an approximation is all you can achieve with these methods.  But there is also anti-differentiation, which many people conflate with the integral (unfortunately).

Not every function is anti-differentiable even though they can still be integrable. Thus a strict equivocation is false.  Anti-differentiation is a transformative process applied to a function which generates a new function with the property, by definition, of having a derivative equal to the original function.

Just know that all youre dong is finding an area under a function. Thats what should be conjured up when you hear "integrate". When you hear "anti-differentiate" then you should think of a very particular and definitionally-distinct notion; any overlap between the two concepts is a proven notion, not a definitional one.  Moreover, one does not always imply the other.  The differences in technique is something for a calculus class to teach.

Comment: What would the function be?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586107/what-is-the-difference-between-an-indefinite-integral-and-an-antiderivative

Comment: The integral (or definite integral) was first studied and was defined by the area under the curve.  The connection to anti-differentiation was later proven, and gave rise to the term "indefinite integral", as a form which describes the area under a function when the interval has yet to be decided, or defined, hence "indefinite".  The indefinite integral is thus distinguished from the area of a defined interval, which uses the term "definite integral". But both are used for integration, ie finding area. That was and has always been the intentions.